# Encrypting messages in ASP.NET to be stored in SQL db

Tags: asp.net, .net, encryption

I am working on an ASP.NET Core WebApi and I will have to store long messages between users in the database.
I was thinking on the way of storing it safely. Keeping it as a plain text might not be the best option.
My questions are:

1. what tools can I use for encryption and decryption? is there something built in .NET I can use?
2. where to put encryption/decryption? controller is of course in the App layer, it sends command or query via mediator. Commands/queries and handlers are placed in domain layer. Should controller already encrypt the message inside the action method, or would you rather have command/query handler do it right before writing/reading from database via repository?

Comment: What's wrong with plain text? If someone can get into your database then you already have a data breach. And communication between will be encrypted. Unless you want end-to-end encryption, in which case the users need to negotiate encryption between each other, not with the database.